# Check if Variable is smaller than others, and which one its smaller than. PHP

Tags: php

I have been working on my scoring system and came accros this.
I have 4 vars.

```
$newscore
$score1
$score2
$score3
```

I want to see if new score is lower than the 3 others, and if so which ones. The scoring system requires you to have the lowest possible score.

I have the following code:

```
if($newscore > $score1){

               if($newscore > $score2){

                    if($newscore < $score3){

                        //has to be score3 to replace.

                    }

                }else{

                    ...

                }

            }
```

But what I'm wondering is if I will have to continue on with all these if statements, or is there something a lot shorter and easier? I need to replace the the score that it is smaller than, but not the one its larger than. Score 1 2 and 3 are all the players stats. And if I do have to continue on with all the if statements, how would the code look (its baffling my logic)?

Comment: How about you save you scores in a database table and query the result. This way you can easy change them anytime you like without tampering with your code. Alternatively, you can look in to the switch statement, it's a superb substitute for if-else statement

Comment: So the question boils down to the question: Why are there score_1_, score_2_, score_3_ instead of a/any other structure that does not require this (manual) numbering?

Comment: It's time use any framework.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi It is in a database, what query would I use?

Comment: If you find yourself numbering variables like `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, then you should probably be using something like an array instead; and incredibly, there is a min() function that will work with arrays

Comment: OP does not want the best of 3 scores, he wants to know if the new score is better than one or more previous scores, and if so, which ones. Nobody ever played any video game?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

EDIT: As you're using a database,  you would execute the query similar to this:

`SELECT scores FROM scores_table` replacing the table name and column name with your corresponding data.

```
$scores = [$score1, $score2] // add as many as you like

$new_score = $scores[0]; // assign a baseline
foreach ($scores as $score) {
    if ($score < $new_score) {
        $new_score = $score;
    } 
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use an array

```
$scores = array(8, 15, 10); //previous scores

$new_score = 5;

$new_score_smallest = true;

foreach($scores as $score) {
 if($score < $new_score) {
  $new_score_smallest = false;
 }
}

if($new_score_smallest) {
 echo "Best score!";
}
else {
 echo "Not the best score :(";
}
```

If you only want to remember the 3 best scores:

```
$scores = array(5, 6, 8);
$new_score = 7;

for($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++) {
    if($new_score < $scores[$i]) {
        $scores[$i] = $new_score;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_search` and `min`

```
$newscore = 2;
$scores = array($score1, $score2, $score3);
if($newscore < min($scores)){
$scores[array_search(min($scores), $scores)] = $newscore;
}
```

---

array `$score` lowest score will be updated if `$newscore` is inferior

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$newscore = 78;
$score1 = 23;
$score2 = 201;
$score3 = 107;

$max = max([$score1, $score2, $score3]);

if ($max < $newscore) {
    echo "New best score ! ({$newscore})";
} else {
    echo "Not the best score !\nCurrent: {$newscore}\nBest: {$max}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your scores in an array or anything iterable (like a query result, whether you use PDO or mysqli).

Let's say your scores are in `$scores` array (it will be the same if `$score` is a PDOStatement for example) and ordered (use `ORDER ASC` in your query):

```
$scores = [105, 201, 305];

$newscore = '186';
$hiscore = false;
$beaten = [];

foreach ($score as $k => $score) {
    if ($newscore > $score) {
        $hiscore = true;
        $beaten[] = $score;
        unset($scores[$k]);
    } 
}

if ($hiscore) {
    echo 'New high score!'.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Better than '.implode(', ', $beaten).PHP_EOL;
    echo 'But not better than '.implode(', ', $scores);
} else {
    echo 'Try harder!';
}
```